# Java to C# (Tree / dictionary search)

Tags: c#, java, dictionary

i have some code in java and im trying to translate to C#.

My main problem at this moment its the TreeMaps... I will put some java code that i want translate, and some C# i already did but don´t know if its well done.

JAVA:

```
private TreeMap<String, Node> nodeMap = new TreeMap<String, Node>();
public double[] strategy = new double[NUM_TURNS]
public int pot;

(...)

if (eval.isWinnerFirst(cards[0], cards[1])) 
{
return nodeMap.get(infoSet).pot;
} 
else {
    return -nodeMap.get(infoSet).pot;
    }

(...)

double[] nodeStrategy = nodeMap.get(infoSet).strategy;
```

C# (attempt) (some quots):

```
public Dictionary<string, Node> sort = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
public double[] strategy = new double[NUM_TURNS]
public int pot;

(...)

if (isWinnerFirst(cards[0], cards[1]))
                {
                    if (sort.ContainsKey(infoSet))
                    {
                        return pot;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (sort.ContainsKey(infoSet))
                    {
                        return -pot;
                    }
                }
(...)

if (sort.ContainsKey(infoSet))
            { double[] nodeStrategy = strategy;}
```

---

Someone know how can i do it right?

PS. I have the class Node implemented.

thanks

Comment: Technically, `Dictionary` in c# is the same as `HashMap` in Java, while `SortedDictionary` is closer to `TreeMap` in Java, and since it looks like you might want the result to be sorted, you may want to consider switching

Comment: Maybe it'd be better that you ditch the java code altogether and start from scratch in clean C#. C# is very different from java, (despite the surface similarities) in that C# is a modern, strongly typed language with support for functional constructs (LINQ), whereas java is a poor lacking inexpressive verbose language that is stuck in the 90's. Chances are that you can achieve the same results than your java code with 10% the amount of code in C#, using the proper constructs and language features.

Comment: ok, i already change, but the problem persists xD

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is an exception getting thrown? Do you just get invalid results?

Answer (score -1):

Replace `sort.ContainsKey(infoSet)` by `sort[infoSet]`. The indexer (the [Dictionary.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) property) returns the value associated with the `infoSet` key if the key is found.